# How can i upgrade my computer's ssd and keep all my data, users, settings etc. without having to buy an extra adapter?

Tags: ssd

(How) can I upgrade my computer's SSD and keep all my data, users, settings, etc.(Basically like a backup in mac os timemachine) without having to buy an extra adapter?
I am currently using ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS
Thanks for your help

Comment: in order to get any information from one SSD to the other, both have to be connected to a computer at the same time. If that's what you mean by "extra adapter," then no, there is no way.

Comment: What is the total amount of space used on your current SSD?

Comment: Where are you putting your backups now? Hopefully not on same drive as when drive fails you will lose all your data. Adapters for USB to SSD are relatively inexpensive. I wanted larger SSD, so moved older SSD to an adapter, about $20. And that is now so much faster than all my many USB flash drives, I may not buy any more flash drives for backup. Still use DVD's for most critical data, also.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- You could put those files on a Google Drive, MS Onedrive, or something similar.
- If you have a system with an extra bay and 2 SATA cables you can take out your old disk, put in the new one, install Ubuntu and then mount the old disk.

  - and copy all the files you want to copy, then remove it.
  - or remove all system related files from this 2nd disk. Keeping your personal files and have it permanently added to the system.

In my experience it is better to plan in such a way that you can survive a re-install whenever you want or need to. Backup personal files but keep a text file that holds all the changes you made to the system so you can execute it after a re-install.